# Selecting visible features only of active layer in QGIS with Python?

Tags: pyqgis, select-by-location

I need to select features from the layer_1 which are inside a virtual polygon which is covering all features from layer_2.
I think one of the solution could be to zoom all features from layer_2 and select all visible features from the layer_1. Is it possible? Give me please some key words to search or simple example.
Another way to solve the problem might be to create covering polygon from layer_2 and then make a spatial query.
What do you think which way is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should create a feature from `layer_2` extent:

```
ext = QgsFeature()
ext.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromRect(layer_2.extent()))
```

And now you have few ways to do this. Ex. you can perform the spatial query and select all features from `layer_1` that are inside this polygon created from extent:

```
for feature in layer_1.getFeatures():
    if ext.geometry().contains(feature.geometry())
        # add this feature to selection
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but smth has gone wrong with my code: error in line 37, in <module>
    if ext.contains(feature.geometry()):
AttributeError: 'QgsFeature' object has no attribute 'contains'. Could you help?

Comment: it should be ext.geometry(), I'm going to change that code

Comment: Your magic is working :) Perfect job!